# Sql server update query locking stages?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, locking

Looking at

```
update MyTable
set Status = 1
where Status = 0
```

of course- the `where` is calculated before the actual update.

but does this filtering (`where Status = 0`) is also inside the lock ?

I mean where is the lock ?

here : `update ...`

or here :  `filter and update...`

Comment: An update lock will be taken for the first portion of the search operation.  Then if/when data needs to be updated the update lock will be converted into an exclusive lock.  Take a look at here to get more info on the update lock (http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2009/11/13/update-locks.aspx).

Comment: @ThomasStringer why didn't you post this as answer?

Comment: I strongly suggest using DMV's to see for yourself what is really locked. start with this (inside a transaction) and then choose your columns of interest and filtering. {the code in the next comment}.

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks AS DTL 
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions AS DES 
 ON DES.session_id = DTL.request_session_id
WHERE DES.[status] != N'sleeping'
AND DES.session_id > 50
AND DTL.request_owner_type != N'SHARED_TRANSACTION_WORKSPACE'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two stages to the lock of updated data.  The first is an update lock (U) and the second, provided there is data that needs to be modified, is an exclusive lock (X).  It's a two stage operation in the sense that there is data that needs to be searched in order to determine what/if data needs to be modified.  The update lock will exist for that (or attempt to be attained for the duration of the operation).  Then when data needs to be modified, the update lock will convert into an exclusive lock.

The reason behind this locking mechanism is to prevent deadlocking from the updating data scenario.  Please see [Kalen Delaney's post](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2009/11/13/update-locks.aspx) on more specifics surrounding this.

Take the below for example:

Execute this for connection 1...

```
-- connection 1, leaves an open tran to prevent connection 2 from progressing

use AdventureWorks2012;
go


begin tran

    update HumanResources.Department
    set name = 'This is a new name'
    where DepartmentID = 11;

--commit tran
```

Then in another session, attempt the following update:

```
use AdventureWorks2012;
go

update HumanResources.Department
set name = 'This is a conflicting tran'
where DepartmentID = 11;
```

What we have here is an update lock that is waiting because there is already an exclusive lock on the resource that the update lock is trying to get (an update lock is not compatible with an exclusive lock).  The above scenario is used to "halt" the update lock conversion to exclusive lock.

You can see this by looking at the `sys.dm_tran_locks` DMV:

```
use AdventureWorks2012;
go

select
    resource_type,
    resource_description,
    resource_associated_entity_id,
    request_mode,
    request_status
from sys.dm_tran_locks
where resource_database_id = db_id();
```

You should have similar results for the output of the above query:

[image]

Comment: But if the second query of yours got an update lock and now it is waiting for the first query to complete , and now ( after the first one is finished) - the where clause does not match any rows ? I mean :  let's say that the first query of yours is `update HumanResources.Department
    set name = 'This is a new name' , Departmentid=12
    where DepartmentID = 11;`.....so now the second query thinks it is going to update some rows(it's waiting to get execlusive lock !) , but **now** there arent any rows of `departmentid=11`.....will it scan the table it again ?

Comment: Can you please answer my last comment

Comment: What do you mean, "scan"? I think you might be thinking procedurally here. Can you explain what you perceive to be happening?

Comment: "scan"= will it have to recalculate the where clause in the second query ?